# 'NearMiss' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: python, imbalanced-data, imblearn

[Detailed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cgT8.jpg)

This is the code below which shows the error.

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss
nm = NearMiss()
X_res,y_res=nm.fit_sample(X,Y)
```

Comment: that code fails with `X is not defined`.  is there a small **self contained** runnable example you could share?

Comment: the issue though does seem odd, code inside the library is calling an internal method that just doesn't exist? seems like a library issue most likely, could you provide the version of imblearn? (look for `imblearn.version` if it exists or maybe `imblearn.__version__`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to under sample your imbalanced dataset. For this purpose, you can use `RandomUnderSampler` instead of `NearMiss`.

Try the following code:

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler  

under_sampler = RandomUnderSampler()
X_res, y_res = under_sampler.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Now, your dataset is balanced. You can verify it using `y_res.value_counts()`.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it's better to use `RandomUnderSampler` instead `NearMiss` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "imblearn" package my conda installed a package named "imbalanced-learn" that's why it does not take the data. But it is strange that the jupyter notebook doesn't tell me that "imblearn" isn't installed.